# Solving PDE using singular perturbation theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I am attempting to solve a PDE, namely the Eikonal equation in two dimensions, perturbatively, because the scenario I am solving presents itself in a perturbative manner. The form of the PDE is
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2 +\frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2= f(r,\theta) + \epsilon g(r,\theta)$$

where both $f(r,\theta)$ and $g(r,\theta)$ are singular for some values of $(r,\theta)$ (which are not the same for $f$ and $g$). I know the solution for

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2 +\frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2= f(r,\theta)$$

and have introduced the function $g(r,\theta)$ as a perturbation with the small parameter $\epsilon$. When I naively applied perturbation theory to it, I got a lot of non-sensical aspects to the solution. I recently read about singular perturbation theory and I was wondering if that is what would be applicable here. Any resource that I came across doesn't feature PDEs in such form being solved with singular perturbation theory.

If anyone can tell me that it is actually the singular perturbation theory that I need to apply, then it would be great. As much as I could read about it, I couldn't solve my problem with that. Can anyone suggest a solution or point towards a method or resource that solves a similar problem?

Also, any good resource on the same would be helpful. Thanks!

P.S. $g(r,\theta)$ looks like $\frac{1}{(r^2+d^2-2rd\cos{\theta})^2}$ where $d$ is a constant.

Comment: Standard PT should work. What kind of "non-sensical" aspects do you get?

Comment: @user619894 The $f(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{r^4}$ for me. On using the unperturbed solution as $u=1/r$, the equation for the next order term turns out to be $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}=\frac{r^2}{(r^2 + d^2 -2rd \cos{\theta})^2}$ which when integrated give me an expression that is singular at $d=0$ and at $\theta =0, \pi$. This is very unsettling as the scenario I am solving for and the PDE has no such singularities. This is what I meant when I wrote "non-sensical".

Comment: The $d=0$ case can be solved analytically, you can try and verify that it is consistent with the perturbation expansion.

Comment: @user619894 Yes that is true I can analytically solve for $d=0$ case. However, I am interested in solving it for the complete case and see if the $d \to 0$ limit of that is the same as what we get in the analytical case. Also, I just don't understand why in the first place such singularities should occur and also the other singularities at $\theta=0, \pi$.

Comment: I meant: solve perturbatively for the $d=0$ case and compare it to that analytical result. This will allow you to gauge in indeed there is a problem in the perturbation scheme.

Comment: @user619894 when I solve it for $d=0$ case, I do the same answer in the perturbation scheme and via simple analytic solution expanded in powers of $\epsilon$. But the $d\neq 0$ just doesn't seem to be working! Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you spell out what $f$ is as well?

Comment: @Ian f=1/ $ r^4$

Comment: So you have a singularity at the origin and another singularity at $(d,0)$, I guess, assuming $d>0$? Just speaking heuristically, this suggests that near the origin the $f$ term is dominant and near $(d,0)$ the $g$ term is dominant, so that you cannot do regular perturbation theory globally. You will need to do a perturbative expansion near the origin (where $g$ is not important) and near $(d,0)$ (where $f$ is not important, *no matter how small $\epsilon$ is*) and "match" them.

Comment: @Ian Is that the premise of matched asymptotics that is studied in singular perturbation theory?

Comment: The inner/outer/composite development is one way to do it. There are some others, but validity depends a lot on the problem. The thing I can tell you for sure is that the behavior close enough to $(d,0)$ (for $d>0$) in your problem involves $g$ whenever $\epsilon>0$, no matter how small.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot for the help! But I am not sure if I understand what you mean by inner/outer/composite development. Is it the name of some method or technique, because when I googled it I didn’t find anything relevant. Again thanks a lot for your insights.

Comment: Also I am currently reading stuff on singular perturbation theory and it would take me a while to reach a level enough in the subject to see if we could solve this problem with techniques from the subject. The examples I could find that are solved by singular perturbation theory didn’t involve any examples same as my problem. Hence the question here.

Comment: The name to use to look up this notion is "boundary layer theory". The point is that close enough to the singularity in $g$, i.e. close enough that $g$ becomes on the order of $1/\epsilon$ or larger, $g$ cannot be neglected "even to leading order", which is why this is singular perturbation theory. The idea in boundary layer theory is that there is a region near the singularity in $g$ where $g$ is extremely important and outside that region $g$ is essentially just a correction.